# increasing heartrate

Tags: running

I had been running and wasn't able to bring up my heart rate. Everything else was fine: I had slept well, eat enough, drink enough. I just couldn't get my heartbeat and -pressure up so that I had enough oxygen in my blood. This happens almost once a week now. Does anyone has a good idea what to check or test?

Comment: i think the question belongs to http://fitness.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Go see a doctor if you have real doubts about your health

Comment: @NetStarter fyi, http://fitness.stackexchange.com/ does not feel the same way

Comment: @edmastermind29 i thought these type of questions are according to http://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @NetStarter this was migrated and their community chose to close: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12899/increasing-heartrate

Comment: @edmastermind29 oh got you..